# How to match repeat word separated by delimeter

Tags: regex

I want to create regexp which will accept these values:

`number:number [P]` or `[K]` or both or nothing and now it can repeat it again separated by delimiter `[ + ]` so for example valid values are:

```
15:15
1:0
1:2 K
1:3 P
1:4 P K
3:4 + 3:2
34:14 P K + 3:1 P
```

What I created is this:

```
([0-9]+:[0-9]+( [K])?( [P])?( [+] )?)+
```

This example has just one mistake. It accepts the value:

```
15:15 K P +
```

which shouldn't be allowed.

How should I change it?

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention it can be K P or P K. Or values are valid

```
1:4 K P
```

Comment: There is no mandatory order of `K` and `P`, i.e. it can be `K P` or `P K`?

Comment: I update my question both values are valid

Comment: What regex engine (or programming language) are you using?

Comment: @sp00m I am using java

Comment: Do you need to extract the different items separatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^([0-9]+:[0-9]+(?: P)?(?: K)?(?: \+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+(?: P)?(?: K)?)*)$
```

[Online tryout](http://regex101.com/r/pF4pI5)

**UPDATE:**: Based on your comment, you can use this one for vice-versa, but it will also match `P P` or `K K`

```
^([0-9]+:[0-9]+(?: [KP]){0,2}(?: \+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+(?: [KP]){0,2})*)$
```

Comment: hm nice just one thing I forgot to add it should accept P and K vice versa so 1:4 K P. Can you please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

This regex supports any order for K and P:

```
^[0-9]+:[0-9]+( P| K| K P| P K)?( \+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+( P| K| K P| P K)?)*$
```

Comment: but when I try your example here: http://regex101.com it doesnt work as @Sabuj Hassan example

Comment: When I try it on 34:14 P K + 3:1 P (the longest example line that you give), I get:

MATCH 1
1. [5-9] ` P K`
2. [9-17] ` + 3:1 P`
3. [15-17] ` P`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(\d+:\d+(?:(?: P)?(?: K)?|(?: P)?(?: K)?)?)(?:\s\+\s(?1))?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : start of string
(               : start capture group 1
    \d+:\d+     : digits followed by colon followed by digits
    (?:         : non capture group
    (?: P)?     : P in a non capture group optional
    (?: K)?     : K in a non capture group optional
    |           : OR
    (?: K)?     : K in a non capture group optional
    (?: P)?     : P in a non capture group optional
    )?          : optional
)               : end of group 1
(?:             : non capture group
    \s\+\s      : space plus space
    (?1)        : same regex than group 1
)?              : end of non capture group optional
$               : end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
^(?:[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?:( [KP])(?!\1)){0,2}(?: \+ |$))+$
```

pattern details:

```
^
(?:                    # this group describes one item with the optional +
    [0-9]+:[0-9]+
    (?:                # describes the KP part
        ( [KP])(?!\1)  # capture current KP and checks it not followed by itself
    ){0,2}             # repeat zero, one or two times
    (?: \+ |$)         # the item ends with + or the end of the string
)+$                    # repeat the item group
```

in Java style:

```
^(?:[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?:( [KP])(?!\\1)){0,2}(?: \\+ |$))+$
```

Comment: can you provide some online regexp  tester where this works ? I try one it seems it doesnt work correctly

Comment: @hudi: This regex has been tested with http://regexplanet.com , I wrote it as a raw pattern, you must replace all backslashes with a double backslash for Java.